# Javascript - convert date format to seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help to change this date format to seconds.

```
<div class="calendar" data-fixeddate="July 16, 2017 00:05 am">...</div>
```

**JS:**

want to get this date format to convert this value to seconds.

Please let me know whether we can convert using Javascript or JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind a library - http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your browser console:

`new Date('July 16, 2017 00:05 am').getTime() / 1000`

`Date.getTime` returns the date in milliseconds, divide by 1000 to get seconds.

Additional information about `Date.getDate` may be read at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime